# How to set default value for the drop link in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am using a drop link field disclaimer having 3 values in my sitecore item country, whose data source i have populated using query which is : query:../../*[@@templatename!='Country selection' and @@templatename!='Folder'].

I want to set the default value also so that every time a new item is created the default value for the disclaimer field is set using query.

Also, i don't want to set the default value for the entire drop links but to disclaimer field only which is for a particular item.

Comment: did you get any resolution on this?

Answer (score -1):

Go to disclaimer tempalte standard values and select the country which you want.
When ever a new item gets created , then country will be pre-populated with default value